# Issues while generating entities from Views

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, view

I am using an Oracle database to generate my EF entities and context.
I do not have control over schema, its all provided by client, and I strictly can't change anything over there.
I have to generate entities for various Views.
When I do this, it is adding all non-nullable columns as the keys (as I can see while opening the edmx in XML editor).

How can I specify which columns should be used as keys? Can I do anything in at EF level without changing the schema?

Comment: simply mark you'r desired column with `[Key]` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. We can do this in EF. Select each column in entity, and Set "Entity Key" to "True/ False".